# Why can't the free function begin operate on C arrays while std::begin can in C++14 in some cases?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14, std

I noticed that begin (without namespace specifier) compiles in some situations and fails in others.

Can you guys explain why can it work when it works and why is there a difference due to the use cases?

The code fails to compile the same way under VS2017 15.9.7 and gcc-8.3.0
std=c++14 is used for both.
vs: error C3861: 'begin': identifier not found
gcc: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <array>

struct Struct {
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::array<int, 4> arr;
        std::begin(arr);
        begin(arr);     // works, calls the same as std::begin above
    }

    {
        std::pair<int, int> arr[4];
        std::begin(arr);
        begin(arr);     // works, calls the same as std::begin above
    }

    {
        int arr[4];
        std::begin(arr);
        begin(arr);     // error
    }

    {
        Struct arr[4];
        std::begin(arr);
        begin(arr);     // error
    }
}
```

I expected that begin without the std:: would never work because it's declared in std namespace and no one says using namespace std or using begin. (or if anyone did then there wouldn't be any error)

I debugged into the first two lines marked as 'works' and I saw that it jumps into the same std::begin implementation as one line before.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements marked `"works"` work because the arguments passed to `begin` belong to the same namespace as `begin`.

In the below example:

```
std::array<int, 4> arr;
begin(arr);     // works, calls the same as std::begin above
```

The type of the argument `arr` belongs to the namespace `std::`. The `begin` also belongs to the namespace `std`.

To find `begin` the compiler does not just look at local scope, but also the namespaces that contain the argument's type. This is called [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). And when the compiler looks at the `std` namespace, it finds `begin` and is able to call it.

The case is the same when the type of the argument is `std::pair`

However, in the statements marked "error", the type of the arguments passed to `begin` are a C-style array and a `Struct`. And both of these do not belong to the `std` namespace. So the compiler cannot find `begin` and therefore cannot call it.